# Split of text file to multiple files and upload to data frames pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have data in very ungly format:

```
 Table                501

 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 |Sale|Di|Dv|Cus |Mat         |Valid From|Valid to  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 |88|01|02|dd|20300    |24.05.2012|31.12.9999|
 |889|01|02|dd|20300     |24.05.2012|31.12.9999|
 |890|01|02|dd|20300     |24.05.2012|31.12.9999|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

  Table                55

 ---------------------------------------------------------
 |Sale|Di|Dv|Cus  |Grou|S|Valid From|Valid to  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 |4500|44|55|A|01560    | |11.02.2019|31.12.9999|
 |4500|44|55|BBB|55070    | |30.04.2018|31.12.9999|
 |4500|44|55|D|55080    | |30.04.2018|31.12.9999|
 |4500|44|55|D|55420    | |30.04.2018|31.12.9999|
 |4500|44|55|8834496   |55450    | |30.04.2018|31.12.9999|
 ---------------------------------------------------------

  Table                065

 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 |Sale|Di|Dv|Cus  |Mat         |Valid From|Valid to  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 |4500|44|55|bbbb   |01000     |29.05.2013|31.12.9999|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to used python to extract data from this txt to pandas dataframes = names of the tables are listed behind like Table_065 .

i thought I would read whole txt and split it to multiple txts, replace the lines starting with '-%' and '  %' and then upload it as single tables.

but I got stuck pretty soon:

```
file = open('0400.txt', 'r')
a = [n for n in file.readlines() if not n.startswith(' -') ]
#a = str(a)
#b = [n for n in a.readlines() if not n.startswith(' ') ]
```

it seems that after using the a variable it is no longer string but list, etc.
Simply I need help.
Please, is here anyone who can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with a bit of manipulation and pandas errors handling when converting `9999` year to a `datetime` object

```
import pandas as pd

with open("0400.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [
        [y.strip() for y in x.split("|")] 
        for x in f.readlines() if not x.startswith(" -")]

df = pd.DataFrame(lines[1:], columns=lines[0])
df["Valid to"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Valid to"], errors="coerce").fillna(pd.Timestamp.max.date())
df["Valid From"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Valid From"], errors="coerce")
print(df)

     Sale  Di  Dv      Cus    Mat Valid From    Valid to  
0    0400  01  02  1327260  20300 2012-05-24  2262-04-11  
1    0400  01  02  1327260  20300 2012-05-24  2262-04-11  
2    0400  01  02  1327260  20300 2012-05-24  2262-04-11
```

Comment: Hi, I think it would work fine but first I need to clear the text file from the Table lines -all the tables above are in one text file..Any advice on that one?